# Google Rich Card JSON-LD not detected - Corporate Information

Tags: google-search-console, json-ld, google-rich-snippets-tool, rich-cards

I'm using structured data in order to get **Corporate Information** to appear when people search for the company's name on Google.

I'm following the correct structure (data-type: corporate-contacts - *sorry can't post more than 2 links*) and the Structured Data Testing Tool [marks no error](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwagglio.co), and yet the Rich Card section of the Webmaster Tools does not show/detect any **Rich Cards** as you can see in the following image:

[image: Rich Card Result]

The **Fetch as Google** runs without problems, the **Index Status** shows: *0 total index*, there are no **Blocked Resources**, there's a **Site Map** on site fully configured and the `robots.txt` has the following contents:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

Finally a request to index the root URL and its direct links was made on July 12th, but there are no signs to show if it has finalized or not.

What else can I do in order to show a **Corporate Information card** in the Google Search results for my company?

Comment: [Cross-posted to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45286687/1591669) (it’s a better fit here)

Comment: Search engines are NOT real-time. How long have you waited between steps??

Comment: @closetnoc It has been 12 days since the last time I did all the aforementioned. Maybe I'm just impatient? How much time would it take more or less?

Comment: Not sure on this. Perhaps one of our other users will know more. We get people expecting things to work within minutes here all the time and why my comment. ;-) You may need to wait more, however, I do not want you wasting time either. Cheers!!

Comment: Try resubmitting your sitemap in GWT. It will cause Google to re-crawl everything and that way it often finds things that it hadn't detected before. (You mentioned you made an index request previously, but sometimes Google needs a little prodding.) That should hopefully get your rich snippets detected. As for the data showing up in the Knowledge Graph, as @gabehou said, there's no guarantee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked before, see the link below.

Basically, Google does not guarantee that Rich Snippets will show up for search results.

Some reasons could be

- Marked-up data is potentially misleading.
- Marked-up data is incorrect and the testing tool was not able to catch.
- Marked-up content is hidden from the user.
- The site has very few pages or very few pages with marked-up structured data.

[Rich Snippets not working (and working at the same time?)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82563/rich-snippets-not-working-and-working-at-the-same-time)