# JSON-LD detected by the structured data validation tool, but not by the search console

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data, json-ld

## My problem

I have added JSON-LD structured data to my site about a [local software conference](https://tlv.serverlessdays.io/). The markup is valid in Google's on [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=tlv.serverlessdays.io).

### Structured Data Testing Tool

[image]

However, Google's own Search Console does not detect any structured data on the same URL:

### Search Console

[image]

## What have I read / tried

### Questions and answers here

- [Rich Snippets not working (and working at the same time?)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82563/rich-snippets-not-working-and-working-at-the-same-time)
- [Google Rich Card JSON-LD not detected - Corporate Information](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/108092/google-rich-card-json-ld-not-detected-corporate-information)

Both don't seem to apply - I'm not complaining about search results taking long time to propagate, but about the very JSON-LD being recognized by one Google tool but not by the other.

### Cache

The site as scraped by Google a few good gours after the JSON-LD as in place. The TTL for the HTML files is set to 5 minutes.

## My question

**Why doesn't the search console recognize my structured site data, and how can I fix it?**

Comment: How many time is your site online after publishing of json-ld snippet? Do you have implemented the search console validation before or after publishing of json-ld snippet? You should know, the data in the search console is aggregated from many data centers of Google - it could happen, that you should just wait a bit - i haven't found any obstacles for json-ld reading. The cache version of Google contains the snippet too. Even if json-ld is implemented by something like tag manager - it is on the place, as it should be.

Comment: Thanks @Evgeniy! See my answer - it actually took the search console _one week_ to parse the JSON-LD. Strange.

Comment: One week? What a rocket-like tool ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do is wait. About one week after the site has been submitted, the search console recognized the `JSON-LD`. Why it took 7 days instead of, say, 7 seconds, is beyond my understanding.

I still don't see the event excerpt in the search results - hope that would be available soon.

## Search console recognizes the JSON-LD

[image]

## No metadata on the search results

[image]

## What I want to see

[image]